# Несколько классов в одном теге Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Есть вот такой элемент

```
<p class="color-9 lheight16 marginbott5 x-normal">Сегодня 18:23</p>
```

Как его получить? Вот так не работает

```
$html->find( "p.color-9.lheight16.marginbott5.x-normal");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуйте так

```
$html->find('p[class=color-9 lheight16 marginbott5 x-normal]');
```

Но если хотя бы один символ не будет совпадать (пробел лишний или имена классов местами переставлены), то не найдет.

Comment: да, работает, спасибо