# Simple HTML DOM Parser найти элемент с двумя классами одновременно

Tags: php, html, парсер, dom

Парсю архив Ленты.ру. Нужно выбрать только новости за день, без категорий,
то есть нужны все **div**, у которых присутствуют одновременно классы **item** и **news**, внутри всех этих **div**'ов нужно выбрать элемент a и, условно говоря, вывести/получить **href**.

Версия, которая работает, НО работает неправильно, выглядит так:

```
$news = $html->find( 'div[class=news] a' );
foreach( $news as $element ):
    echo $element->href . "\n";
endforeach;
```

Неправильно потому что выборка идёт только по **div**'ам с классом **news**, а надо выборку по **div**'ам с классами **item** и **news** вместе.

Пробовал так:

```
$news = $html->find( 'div[class=item news] a' );
```

...и так:

```
$news = $html->find( 'div.item.news a' );
```

...и так:

```
$news = $html->find( 'div[class="item news"] a' );
```

Не работает. Варианты эти нашёл соответственно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387958/find-stacked-div-class-with-simple-html-dom-parser) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264525/php-simple-html-dom-parser-select-only-divs-with-multiple-classes). Принципиально ли использовать Simple HTML DOM Parser? Нет, не принципиально. Но с ним я уже знаком и имел опыт использования, поэтому выбор пал на него.

Была ещё такая мысль: сначала найти все **div** с **class**=**item**, потом среди них найти все **div** с **class**=**news**, потом в каждом из них найти **a**, но у меня не получилось. Как я понял, цепочка методов а-ля

```
$news = $html->find( 'div[class=item]' )->find( 'div[class=news] a' );
```

не сработает (у меня не работает). Как быть?

P.S. Добавлю. Сейчас глянул ещё [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561117/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5-simple-html-dom-parser), да, решение рабочее, всё нормально работает. Если полностью прописать все классы:

```
$news = $html->find( 'div[class=item news b-tabloid__topic_news] a' );
```

Но дело в том, что последний класс **b-tabloid__topic_news** там присутствует не везде, то есть его наличие не обязательно. Да, можно наговнокодить алгоритм с массивами, ищем сначала такие, потом другие, склеиваем, сортируем и т.д, но это ИМХО криво. В общем, вопрос можно переформулировать так: как найти все элементы, у которых среди классов есть нужные?

Comment: Может быть лучше взять парсер, что умеет в xpath?С  xpath то легко решается.

Comment: Не проще ли свести задачу до того, чтобы не выбирать элемент по двум классам одновременно? `simplehtmldom` - задумка хорошая, но к сожалению брошенная.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В целом понятно, что данная  библиотека не умеет корректно обрабатывать селекторы, где перечисляются два и более класса подряд. Тем не менее, вы в целом смотрите в нужном направлении, используя форму записи `div[class=...]`.

Рассмотрим исходный тестовый пример:

```
$txt =  <<<HTML
<div>
    <div class="news"><a  href="qwe">qwe123</a></div>
    <div class="items"><a href="asd">asd123<a/></div>
    <div class="news items qwe">
        <a href="zxc">zxc123</a>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$html = str_get_html($txt);
```

пусть наша задача найти `div.news.items` и вывести значение текста ссылки `zxc123`. Как вы и написали, вызов вида

```
$html->find('.news.items a);
```

Возвращает пустой набор. Однако, в целом это эквивалентно записи `div[class="news items"]`. Как известно помимо непосредственного равенства атрибута `=`, возможны и другие формы записи, например, `*=`.

Если глянуть во внутренности `Simple HTML DOM`, то вы обнаружите там следующую функцию тестирования селекторов (код приведен не полностью):

```
protected function match($exp, $pattern, $value) { 
    switch ($exp) {    
        case '=':    
            return ($value===$pattern);    
......
        case '*=':    
            if ($pattern[0]=='/') {    
                return preg_match($pattern, $value);    
            }    
            return preg_match("/".$pattern."/i", $value);    
    }    
    return false;    
}
```

Отсюда видно, что при указании непосредственного равенества, используется обычное сравнение строк (они ранее приводятся к одному регистру). А вот при указании вхождения `*=` используются регулярные выражения. 
Следовательно,  использование подобного селектора решит искомую проблему. Более того, мы можем указать непосредственно регулярное выражение в селекторе. Поэтому код

```
$html->find("div[class*=news items] a");
```

для данного исходного примера успешно найдет экземлпяр ссылки `<a href="zxc">zxc123</a>`.

Как было упомянуто выше, допустимо использование регулярного выражения, поэтому, если исходный текст будет иметь более сложный набор классов `zxc news asd items qwe`, но подходящий нам:

```
    <div class="zxc news asd items qwe">
        <a href="zxc">zxc123</a>
    </div>
```

то написание следующего селектора разрешит эту ситуацию:

```
$html->find("div[class*=news.+items] a");
```

либо если порядок следования классов `items` и `news` может изменится, то возможно следующее выражение:

```
$html->find("div[class*=news.+items|items.+news] a");
```

*зы: такое поведение, вроде, недокументировано, но вроде как и хаком-багом не является, ибо в коде явно прописано условие, проверки первого символа регулярки.*

Comment: Семён Семёныч... Да, так всё работает, большое спасибо. Как я сам-то блин не догадался под капот парсера заглянуть

Comment: @КапитанФлинт я за последнее вермя уже два раза заглядывал, хотя сам его ни разу не использовал :D

Comment: бывает и не такое))))