# Поиск STYLE через HTML DOM parser

Tags: php

Вот сам кусок кода:

```
<div style="float:left;max-width:280px;"><a href="/url.htm" alt="alt text"> <b>anchor</b></a>
```

Есть html код страницы. Нужно собрать ссылки, которые находятся между

```
<div style="float:left;max-width:280px;"><a href="
```

и

```
" alt="
```

Т.е. нужно получить именно - /url.htm

Использую SIMPLE HTML DOM 
Пытаюсь применить такой код, но не работает.

```
$ret = $html->find('div[float:left;max-width:280px; a]');
```

Как получить все ссылки со страницы в таком случае и Засунуть их в массив?

Comment: выдает -  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

Comment: та же ошибка появляется.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653055/simple-html-dom-parser-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: Видел этот пример. Класс, ID легко найти, но как определить div по style ??? Я этого понять не могу.

Comment: `div[style="...."] a` ? вам в условии атрибут проверять надо на равенство, а не его значение просто вписывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант решения задачи - забейте на SIMPLE HTML DOM, и используйте обычные регулярки.

```
preg_match_all ( '~width:280px;"><a href="(.*?)"~',$html,$matches);
```

Результат будет в `$matches[1]`

Demo - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8c9f7559de8d36f78fd03032bb332753e136aef