# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, как найти нужную ссылку?

Tags: php, html, парсер, simple-html-dom

Как спарсить нужную ссылку, если на странице много одинаковых классов и номер всегда разный я про [0, и т.п.], известно начало ссылки, класс. Пример:

```
<?php
include 'dom.php';
$html = file_get_html ('$_POST['name']);
$link = $html->find('a[class=classname href=http://site.co/]');
?>
```

Нужно искать по двум параметрам:

1. класс
2. начало ссылки

И вытащить именно ссылку, а не название, при этом я буду эту ссылку вставлять в другую переменную.

Comment: С этим парсером такое сделать маловероятно.

Comment: я уже слишком много сделал, чтобы переходить на другой язык)

Comment: Найти нужную ссылку с нужным классом на странице легче через регулярку, а не этим парсером. Хотя многие, наверное, тут будут утверждать об обратном, но тогда хотелось бы решение от таких людей увидеть (это я для утверждающих написал) ;)

Comment: там [регулярку можно вписать в атрибуты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653188/223826). да и кто мешает выбрать ссылки по классу, а потом из результата отфильтровать по url руками?

Comment: это же не конец скрипта, дальше мне нужно вставлять эту ссылку в другую переменную, а потом собрать информацию из этой переменной.

Comment: я не шарю в пхп, тупо пишу скрипт, пользуясь обычной логикой.

Comment: мне нужен лишь пример, чтобы я понял и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В выражении поиска указываете класс ссылки обычным образом `a.classname`, а начало ссылки проверяйте через атрибут `[href^='....']`

```
$body = <<<HTML
<div>
    <a class="link" href="http://yandex.ru">yandex</a>
    <a class="link needle" href="http://site.co">site.co</a>
    <a class="link" href="http://google.com">google</a>
    <a class="xxx" href="http://bing.com">bing</a>
</div>
HTML;


$html = str_get_html($body);
$links = $html->find("a.link[href^='http://site.co']");
foreach($links as $l){
    print_r($l->href);
}
```

в результате данного кода `$links` будет содержать массив подходящих ссылок. В данном случае это будет единственная ссылка, указывающая на `site.co`

---

Для получения первого элемента из найденных передайте индекс `0` в метод `find`. Сохранить значения ссылки и ее текста для дальнейшего использования вы можете с помощью свойств `href` и `plaintext`:

```
$lnk = $html->find("a.link[href^='http://site.co']", 0);
$url = $lnk->href;
$txt = $lnk->plaintext;
```

Comment: Действительно работает. Плохо, что только один класс можно указать.

Comment: @Visman, как я уже в комментах к вопросу писал, то [можно запихать регулярку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653188/223826) `a[class*=.....]`, где вместо `...` будет выражение для фильтрации класса. То есть например `a[class*=class1.+class2]` получит ссылки, содержащие оба класса. ну или там `a[class*=link\d+]` найдет все `link1, link2` и т.п.

Comment: Тогда этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/561117/186083 обозначил как дубликат вопроса с вашим ответом.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @АртурКотов  если это то, что надо, то [отметьте ответ как правильный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: А как мне потом это записать в обычную переменную, не выводя на страницу?

Comment: @АртурКотов дополнил ответ.